# Not able to understand this function definition

Tags: c, function

How to interpret this function definition? How should I pass arguments to it?

```
void matmul(float (*A)[N],int BlockX, int BlockY)
```

Comment: This is C/C++. (*A)[N] is an Array of N Pointers to float.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument is a pointer to an array of `N` elements:

```
float a[N];
matmul(&a, 2, 3);
```

(Note that `N` has to be a compile-time constant in C89 and C++; in C89 it would essentially have to be `#define`d as some literal value. In C99 you have variable-length arrays.)

Since arrays decay to pointers, you can also feed it an array:

```
float b[M][N];
matmul(b, 2, 3);
```

Comment: But in function definition they are accessing it as 2D array i'm not getting it..

Comment: Well, the pointer could of course also be the decay of an array: `float b[M][N]; matmul(b, 2, 4);` Edited.

Comment: No, for mondern C, aka C99, `N` must not necessarily be a compile time constant.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Ah, VLAs.... that could get seriously confusing, though: `int N = 5; void matmul(float(*)[N], int, int); int main() { N = 3; float a[N][N]; matmul(a, 1, 1); }` Weird...

Comment: @KerrekSB, you seem to be confused, yes :) the compiler wouldn't be. The `N` the function sees (uses) is the `N` in the *definition* of the function, not at the point of calling. See my answer how one would define such things correctly.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I think I get it, but I'm just noting that these VLAs allow you some serious betrayal of the type system. It's very understandable that those weren't added to C++!

Comment: @KerrekSB, betrayal is a strong word. These are dynamic types. C++ has its own elastics with the type system by introducing virtual inheritance. These introduce at least as many problems. But let's stick to C, this is a C question. And C99 is the current standard for C.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of writing the same prototype would be

```
void matmul(float A[][N],int BlockX, int BlockY)
```

which better shows what this usually supposed to receive, a two dimensional array, for which `N` is

- a compile time integer constant (not a `const` variable!) if you only have C89
- any integer expression which can be evaluated at the point of the *definition* if you have modern C99

The other dimension is not specified and you have to know or transmit it somehow.

It looks to me that this interface is an oldish one, since it seems to use `int` parameters to pass size information. The modern way to do this (and avoid 32/64 bit problems and stuff like that) would be to use `size_t` for such quantities.

If by chance the two parameters would correspond to the "real" matrix dimension, in modern C your definition should look like

```
void matmul(size_t m, size_t n, float A[m][n]) {
   ...
}
```

where it is important that `m` and `n` come before `A`, such that they are already known, there.